# [LWC]: Updating an @api object referenced in a child component doesn't update the value in the child

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, parent-to-child

I have a playground to demonstrate [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/h19PriouA/8/edit).

I have two variables that are being linked to the child component. `myString` is a String and `myObject` is an Object. Both variables are being updated 500ms after the component gets inserted in the document. However only the string type's value gets sent down to the child. The object type variable gets its value updated as well but that never reaches the child.

Here's a screenshot from the developer console from the playground. It should have one more `"Object value is [object Object]"` but that never gets printed out. Why does the updated object value doesn't get sent to the child component?

[image]

**EDIT**
Adding the code from the playground below since SF will delete the playgrounds in December.

Parent's html:

```
<template>
    <c-child
        load-my-string={myString}
        load-my-object={myObject}
    ></c-child>
</template>
```

Parent's JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  

    @api myString = '';
    @api myObject = {
        arr: undefined,
        bool: true
    };

    connectedCallback() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-operation
        this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.myString = 'Hello, this is a string';
            this.myObject.arr = [1,2,3];
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Child's HTML:

```
<template>
  <div>{theString}</div>
  <div>{theObject.arr}</div>
</template>
```

Child's JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

/**
 * Show an item
 */
export default class Child extends LightningElement {
    @track theString;
    @track theObject;

    set loadMyString(value) {
        console.log('String value is ' + value);
        this.theString = value;
    }
    @api get loadMyString() {
        return this.theString;
    }
    set loadMyObject(value) {
        console.log('Object value is ' + value, value.arr);
        this.theObject = value;
    }
    @api get loadMyObject() {
        return this.theObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, the "myObject" itself doesn't change, rather its content does. Have a look at the new playground version [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/h19PriouA/9/edit) and you will see the child renders [1, 2, 3] from the loadMyObject.arr value.

Re-rendering is invoked at the parent level, but the @api set function doesn't need to be invoked since the child already has reference to the "myObject" proxy object with its updated value.

To get the set function called, you want to change the parent:

From:

```
this.myObject.arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

To:

```
this.myObject = {...this.myObject, arr:[1,2,3]};
```

Using the spread operator as per salesforce-sas's suggestion.

Comment: Interesting, what would I do if I need the child to be notified of the change on the object?

Comment: Updated answer to cover this point

Comment: By the way, the child is already "notified" in a way, because it gets re-rendered. You could use the lifecycle hooks to detect this.

Comment: Are you thinking of the `renderedCallback()`? Also thank you for updating your answer, that's very clever.

Comment: Either the renderedCallback() or the render() one - check out [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lifecycle_hooks). You could cheat and do something in render then return [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).render().

Comment: better way of doing it would be `this.myObject = {...this.myObject, arr:[1,2,3]}`